# How to retrieve the data from the database using CoreData

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, core-data

I am learning core data concept and i want to use this in my simple app.

I have did the sample from the below link.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Core_Data_Tutorial_%28Xcode_4%29

i have did everything and followed the steps described in that link.

Generally i have added the data to tables(entity) and fetched the records using core data.

But my question is==> Once i closed(killed) the app from simulator (or) device means, the data stored in db also cleared. Next time when open that app again means, db will be empty.

In the above link also, this would be happened.

How to store data permanently in db(sqlite) using core data?

i want data(records) which i stored previous in that db. How to achieve it?

Please Help in this regards!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial from raywenderlich would be a good start to learn for coredata... below is the link for the same...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

For your question : `i want data(records) which i stored previous in that db. How to achieve it?`

if you will delete the app either from device or simulator your database will be deleted. If you are testing on simulator and you have made db file in Resource bundle then everytime you run the project, Your database will be replaced by your database file in Project bundle..

please see clear yourself how project refers to db while running in simulator.